# Error with multiple 'orderBy', 'where' clauses with inequality operator in Firestore query

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I encountered an issue while using Firestore in my Flutter app with the following code snippet:

```
query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('posts')
                .where(
                  'noOfLikes',
                  isGreaterThan: -1,
                )
                .orderBy('noOfLikes', descending: true)
                .where(
                  'createdAt',
                  isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime.now()
                      .subtract(
                        const Duration(days: 1),
                      )
                      .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                )
                .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true);
```

The code provided aims to query the 'posts' collection based on 'noOfLikes' greater than -1 and 'createdAt' within the last 24 hours. However, when running this query, I encountered the following error:

> The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([noOfLikes]), true]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([createdAt])' when an inequality operator is invoked. 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': query.dart:1 Failed assertion: line 705 pos 11: 'field == orders[0][0]'

I expected the Firestore query to work as intended, allowing me to order the results first by 'noOfLikes' in descending order and then by 'createdAt' in descending order for posts created within the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explicit: you can only order by and have a range filter (`>`, `<`, etc) on a single field in a Firestore query. From the documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Since your code tries to perform a range filter on both `noOfLikes` and `createdAt`, it can't be executed by Firestore and it thus raises an error.

The solution is to perform one of the conditions on the database itself, and the other one in your application code. Alternatively, you can switch to a database that better supports this type of query.